# Printing longest subsequence of letters using Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.7, subsequence

Write a block of code to print the longest subsequence of letters out of an input string. 
- First, ask user to input any string.
- You code should print the longest sub-string of the input string, which contains only letters of the English alphabet, including both uppercase and lowercase letters.

**If there are multiple subsequences of the same longest length, the code returns the first one.** 
**If input_str doesn’t contain any letter, the function returns an empty string.**

For example,

- for input string 'ab24[AaBbCDExy0longest]', it should print 'AaBbCDExy'.
- for input string 'a a a1234b|c|d ', it should print 'a'.
- for input string '12345 ', it should print "" (empty string).

Tried the following code but in vain:

```
# Your code here

#longest_letterSeq = '' 
def longestSubstring(s): 
    longest_letterSeq = '' 
    i = 0
    while(i<len(s)): 

        curr_letterSeq = '' 

        # For letter substring  
        while(i<len(s) and s[i].isalpha()): 
            curr_letterSeq += s[i] 
            i+= 1

        # Case handling if the character is not letter     
            if(i< len(s) and not(s[i].isalpha())) : 
                i+= 1

            if(len(curr_letterSeq) > len(longest_letterSeq) ): 
                longest_letterSeq = curr_letterSeq 

    return longest_letterSeq

str = input("Please input your string here: ")

print(longestSubstring(str))
```

Can someone help with the edited or correct code?

Answer (score 2):

One option is using `re.findall` with `max`:

```
import re
max(re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+',  'ab24[AaBbCDExy0longest]'), key=len)
# 'AaBbCDExy'

max(re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', 'a a a1234b|c|d '), key=len)
# 'a'
```

---

Small hack to contemplate cases where there are no matches:

```
max(re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', '12345 ') or [''], key=len)
# ''
```

Though I'd suggest you to go with the more readable approach:

```
r = re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', '12345 ') 
if r:
    out = max(r, key=len)
else:
    out = ''
```

Or as @deepstop suggests with the conditional expression:

```
out = max(r, key=len) if r else ''
```

Comment: Should be `key=len` on the 3rd line of the last example, or just `out = max(r, key=len) if r else ''`

Comment: Yes thanks @Deepstop . Yes just wanted to go for a more readable one for OP. Thanks anyways, lets add that too

Comment: NP. I thought as much.

Answer (score 0):

like yatu, my first though on such a problem would be regex. However I have offered a solution based on your approach. the problem in your code is that you only increment i when the character is an alpha. So for the string `abc123` you will increment i 3 times. but as the next char is not alpha you dont incerase i. which means i is now stuck with a value of 3 and thats less than the length of the string 6. so your function is stuck in an infinite loop since you stop increasing i.

A simplified version of your code can be written as below. essentially there is no need for a second while loop. Infact there is no need for a while loop at all, you can just use a for loop to iterate over each character in the string

```
def longestSubstring(string):
    longest_letterSeq = ''
    curr_letterSeq = ''
    for char in string:
        if char.isalpha():
            curr_letterSeq += char
        else:
            if len(curr_letterSeq) > len(longest_letterSeq):
                longest_letterSeq = curr_letterSeq
            curr_letterSeq = ''
    return longest_letterSeq

my_strings = ['ab24[AaBbCDExy0longest]', 'a a a1234b|c|d ', '12345']
for string in my_strings:
    longest = longestSubstring(string)
    print(f'the longest string in "{string}" is "{longest}"')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
the longest string in "ab24[AaBbCDExy0longest]" is "AaBbCDExy"
the longest string in "a a a1234b|c|d " is "a"
the longest string in "12345" is ""
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to replace all non-letters with a space, split, and then choose the longest string.

```
import re

def func(s) :
    l = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]+', ' ', s).split()
    l.append('')  # Append an empty string so the list is bound not to be empty.
    return max(l, key=len)

func('ab24[AaBbCDExy0longest]')
func('foo2bar')
func('')
```